# Display list items grouped in columns

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a large list of items which I want to group by condition and display them in table columns. Which is the preferred way to do this?

Can paging library help me with that?

I tried adding items to `MutableList<List<Item>> (index, item)` but I get slow performance.

```
private fun createData(idSection: Int) {
    println("idSection = $idSection")
     viewModelScope.launch {
         showDialogLoading(true)
         delay(3000)
         scoreWithStudentScoreAndStudent()?.collect {
             cells.clear()

             val filtered = it.filter { scoreWithStudentScoreAndStudent ->
                 scoreWithStudentScoreAndStudent.studentScoreAndStudent.firstOrNull()?.studentScore?.idSection == idSection
             }
             println("${filtered.size}")

             if (filtered.isNotEmpty()) {
                 println("NOT EMPTY")
                 _scores.value = filtered.map { scoreWithStudentScoreAndStudent ->
                     scoreWithStudentScoreAndStudent.score
                 }
                 filtered.forEachIndexed { index, scoreWithStudentScoreAndStudent ->
                     _test.value =
                         scoreWithStudentScoreAndStudent.studentScoreAndStudent.sortedWith(
                             compareBy<StudentScoreAndStudent> { studentScoreAndStudent ->
                                 studentScoreAndStudent.student.lastName
                             }
                                 .thenBy { studentScoreAndStudent ->
                                     studentScoreAndStudent.student.firstName
                                 }
                         )
                     _students.value = _test.value.map { studentScoreAndStudent ->
                         studentScoreAndStudent.student
                     }
                     cells.add(index, _test.value)
                 }
                 showDialogLoading(false)
                 //showDialogLoading(false)
                 scoresTableVisibility(true)
             } else {
                 scoresTableVisibility(false)
                 showDialogLoading(false)
                 textAndIconVisibility2(false)
             }
         }
         scoresTableVisibility(false)
     }
}
```

Comment: You had better to post some code. Are you working with [*Jetpack Compose*](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) in your project?

Comment: Yes i use Jetpack Compose. I tried to update post with some code. I tried to get from filtered list three lists. One student list (_students), one header list (_test) and cells so i can display then in a table with freezed headers. The cells list is to hold the students scores grouped by header.